# 404 Not Found Error Spring Boot - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: spring-boot

1. Spring boot:v2.2.4.RELEASE Tomcat: Apache Tomcat/9.0.30 Jdk:13 Using
   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect`help me to resolve`

   I get below Result in postman:

   ```
   {
   "timestamp": "2020-02-17T02:46:49.724+0000",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": "No message available",
   "path": "/insert" 
   }
   ```

   When I hit postman I get below details in eclipse console. Anyone
   help  to solve this issue. Eclipse console:

   ```
   INFO 1512 ---
   [nio-8080-exec-2] [Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing
   Spring Dispatcher Servlet 'dispatcher Servlet' INFO 1512 ---
   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
   Initializing Servlet 'dispatcher Servlet' INFO 1512 ---
   [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
   Completed initialization in 2 ms
   ```

   application.properties:

   ```
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oneacademydb?useSSL=false
   spring.datasource.username=root
   spring.datasource.password=root
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
   ```

   controller:

   ```
   @RestController @RequestMapping("/api/v1") 
    public class UserdetailsController {
   @Autowired
   private UserdetailsRepository userRepository;

   @GetMapping("/users")
   public List<Userdetails> getAllUsers() {
       return userRepository.findAll();
   } }
   ```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication @EnableJpaAuditing 
public class OneacademyApplication {    
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OneacademyApplication.class, args);   
  } }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository 
public interface UserdetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<Userdetails,Integer>{ 
  }
```

model:

```
@Data
@Entity 
@Table(name="Userdetails")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class) 
public class Userdetails {      
  @Id   
  @Column
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;   
  @Column
  private String firstname;
  @Column   
  private String lastname;  
  @Column   
  private String email; 
  @Column
  private int mobile;   
  @Column
  private String address;
  @Column
  private String state;
  @Column 
  private String city;  
  @Column   private int pincode;
  @Column   private String password;    
  @Column   private String usertype;    
  @Column   private int otp;    
  @Column   private String created_user;    
  @Column   private String updated_user;    
  @Column   private char status;        
  @Override     public String toString() {
        return "Userdetails [id=" + id + ", firstname=" + firstname + ",
lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email
                + ", mobile=" + mobile + ", address=" + address + ", state=" + state + ", city=" + city + ", pincode="
                + pincode + ", password=" + password + ", usertype=" + usertype + ", otp=" + otp + ", created_user="
                + created_user + ", updated_user=" + updated_user + ", status=" + status + "]";     }

    public Userdetails() {}          }
```

Comment: Please confirm if the Controller class is component-scanned ? If not sure , update the question with the package structure and better formatting for the code shared.

Comment: in your code no /insert api available as you are showing, if these in some different package you need to mention @Component scan